# Porting iostream input code from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, operator-overloading, iostream

This is C++ code for reading traces of address of main memory for cache memory simulation:

```
 char hex[20];
 ifstream infile;
 infile.open(filename,ios::in);
 if(!infile) {
    cout<<"Error! File not found...";
    exit(0);
 }
 int set, tag, found;
 while(!infile.eof()) { //Reading each address from trace file
      if(base!=10) {
           infile>>hex;
           address = changebase(hex, base);
      } else {
           infile>>address;
      }
      set = (address / block_size) % no_set;
      tag  = address / (block_size * no_set);
 }
```

I have converted this to C# code:

```
 char[] hex = new char[20];
 FileStream infile=new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

 if (infile == null) {
     Console.Write("Error! File not found...");
     Environment.Exit(0);
 }
 int set;
 int tag;
 int found;
 while (!infile.CanRead) { //Reading each address from trace file
     if (@base != 10) {
         infile >> hex;
         address = changebase(hex, @base);
     } else {
         infile >> address;
     }
     set = (address / block_size) % no_set;
     tag = address / (block_size * no_set);
 }
```

The problem is on line `infile >> hex;`
C# is giving syntax errors, as shift right operator cannot be applied to string operators.

Why this is not working? I'm making a small cache hit and miss calculation project.

Answer (score 12):

To quantify what Eric means:

C++ is quite flexible in the operators that can be overloaded.  It has become an "idiom" that the bitshift operators `<<` and `>>` also be used for input and output.  This actually makes kind of sense as it is a logical construct and the eye registers some kind of "flow" between objects.

In C#, you don't overload those operators.  What Eric means is, you need to say explicitly, on a stream object, to write (or indeed, read) something.  This means calling the methods directly.

In essence you're doing the same thing - the operator overloading is just a nice shortcut, but at the end of the day *some* method is going to be called - be it a nice decorative "operator overload" or a plain old function call with a name.

So, in C++ we might write:

```
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

Whereas in C# we'd write:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

If we ignore the fact that `std::cout` could potentially be different from the console window (this is illustrative), the concept is exactly the same.

To expand on the idea of the operators, you'll also have probably come across things such as `stringstream`..  a class that acts like a stream for strings.  It's really quite useful:

```
std::stringstream ss;
int age = 25;
ss << "So you must be " << age << " years old.";
```

In C#, we achieve this with the `StringBuilder` class:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int age = 25;
sb.Append("So you must be ").Append(age).Append(" years old");
```

They both do *exactly* the same thing.  We could also do:

```
sb.AppendFormat("So you must be {0} years old", age);
```

This is more akin (in my opinion) to the more C-like `sprintf` methods, or more recently, [boost's format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/doc/format.html).

Comment: You have a strange definition of "nice" ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow, "that's what she said"? :)

Comment: Why are you calling it a “sort of” idiom, when the STL (which is part of the C++ spec) uses it?

Comment: @svick, it was more of a turn of phrase than anything - regardless, I have edited :)

Answer (score 9):

C# does not use the bizarre C++ convention that bitshifting also means stream manipulation. You'll have to actually call methods for I/O.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, make the answer helpful by adding insight on _which_ methods to call? As it stands it is a, hilariously funny, comment.

Comment: ok, but how can i do that, i am a beginner, please provide some explanation

Comment: You write `infile.` and then wait for Intellisense to step in.

Comment: @FredOverflow but… but… I use Vim. Does that mean I cannot do I/O in C#? :(

Comment: @FredOverflow Which is the same as waiting forever. :P

Comment: Instead of `infile >> hex` you write `hex = infile.someMethod()` which is probably called `readByte()` or `getByte()` or something.

Comment: @FredOverflow [`Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx) and [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write.aspx). Note that it's unformatted, unlike C++' `>>` and `<<`, i.e. it just reads bytes instead of integers/strings/Booleans/whatever.

Comment: @FredOverflow Does that do the same thing as >> operator??

Comment: Look, there are languages where `base ^ exponent` means exponentiation. In C#, you must write `Math.pow(base, exponent)` or something instead, "even though" C# also has the `^` operator. Just forget about the existence of the `>>` operator in C++ (and C#), will you?

Comment: @rightfold Don't let the emacs mob catch you, I just saw them trespassing with pitchforks and torches ;)